# How can I sort numbers in arraylist?

Tags: android

How can I sort numbers in arraylist , I have this arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
{"H - 1","N - 15","C - 7","Q - 95","Z - 193"} //Values in array above
```

*Output should be*

```
Z - 193
Q - 95
N - 15
C - 7
H - 1
```

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre].

Comment: @JörgWMittag I don't have idea how can I do it.

Comment: You can do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mre] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the numbers unique? Or the letters? If so, then you could do this:

First I would split your values to get the number and letters apart from each other:

```
String[] parts = value.split(" - ");
Integer number = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
String letter = parts[0];
```

Then I would store it in a `Map`:

```
Map<Integer,String> exampleMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

You can put your items in this map with:

```
exampleMap.put(number,letter);
```

Because you use `TreeMap` (which implements `SortedMap`), your items will automaticly sorted when you iterate it:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : exampleMap.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
```

When iterating, you can access the key and the value, so then you can also concatenate the two parts together and put them in an `String` array.

Comment: I can't do it by Collections.sort ?

Comment: `Collections.sort() ` only accepts `List<T>` where `T` is the type of class you compare with. If you try to sort your array (after converting it to an list with `Arrays.asList()`) it will sort by the letters first, because you didn't split your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collections.sort with a custom comparator to decide the sort order. The current accepted answer by `Ben van Hartingsveldt 'Y'` doesn't handles duplicates in the ArrayList.

```
Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String a, String b) {
                String tokA[] = a.split(" - ");
                String tokB[] = b.split(" - ");
                int valueCompare = Integer.parseInt(tokB[1]) - Integer.parseInt(tokA[1]);
                if(valueCompare == 0) {
                    return tokA[0].compareTo(tokB[0]);
                } else {
                    return valueCompare;
                }
            }
        });
```

The above code first sorts by the number in descending order, if the number is equal for any two elements then it sorts based on the first part in ascending order.
So for example if list has following elements:
`{"H - 1","E - 1", "N - 15","C - 7","Q - 95","Z - 193", "Z - 193"}`
then output would be:

```
Z - 193
Z - 193
Q - 95
N - 15
C - 7
E - 1
H - 1
```

[Ideone Link](https://ideone.com/5JFlUx)